# resolver.resolveComponentFactory error

Tags: angular

I am following [this post](https://engineering-game-dev.com/2016/08/19/angular-2-dynamically-injecting-components/), attempting to dynamically create components (based on json data, for that matter) -

But this fragment of code:

`ngOnInit() {
        // Create our component now we're initialised
        let componentFactory = this.resolver.resolveComponentFactory(MyDynamicComponent);
        this.componentReference = this.dynamicTarget.createComponent(componentFactory);
    }`

produces a compilation error saying `metadata_resolver.js:508: Uncaught Error: Can't resolve all parameters for MyDynamicComponent: (?).`

The IDE hints: `Argument type MyDynamicComponent is not assignable to parameter type Type<MyDynamicComponent>`

I am not sure how I should consume this and modify my invocation. What is the catch?

Comment: Could you please add more code? What does `MyDynamicComponent` look like? How are you using it?

Comment: @yurzui Thanks mate for your interest, further search proved I was missing this declaration `entryComponents: [MyDynamicComponent]` in NgModule.Everything works fine now.

Answer (score 4):

The current version of Ionic **v6.1.8** is not compatible with **Angular 14**. Apparently, it's been fixed in a dev release but it's not stable yet. Have a look here https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-framework/issues/25353, you can update `@ionic/angular` to version `6.1.9-dev.11654275237.1b595be3` and re-run `npm install`. Should work fine for now, if you wanna be on the edge.

Comment: I don't think I was using Ionic 6 years ago when posting this question, but if we are speaking about ng14 then it (Ivy) doesn't require component factory or entryComponents anymore.